# MPLS L2VPN on Cisco CSR

Tags: cisco

I need single /24 private IP address space that spans two locations across a L2VPN with Cisco CSR 1000v (ax license and vmware vsphere hypervisor)?
Tunnel and VC status up but cant connect from location A to location B in same single network.
Same config good working in Cisco 2911 but with low performance ~50mbps.

```
Config:
    mpls label protocol ldp
    l2vpn
    !
    interface Tunnel0
     ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.252
     ip tcp adjust-mss 1390
     mpls ip
     mpls mtu 1430
     tunnel source 185.3.xx.yy
     tunnel destination 185.25.xx.yy
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet1
     ip address 185.3.xx.yy 255.255.255.0
     negotiation auto
    interface GigabitEthernet2.200
     encapsulation dot1Q 200
     xconnect 10.1.1.2 200 encapsulation mpls
      mtu 1430
    !
    mpls ldp router-id Tunnel0 force

Info:
    csr01#sh mpls l2transport binding
      Destination Address: 10.1.1.2,VC ID: 200
        Local Label:  21
            Cbit: 1,    VC Type: Ethernet,    GroupID: 7
            MTU: 1430,   Interface Desc: n/a
            VCCV: CC Type: CW [1], RA [2], TTL [3]
                  CV Type: LSPV [2]
        Remote Label: 18
            Cbit: 1,    VC Type: Ethernet,    GroupID: 7
            MTU: 1430,   Interface Desc: n/a
            VCCV: CC Type: CW [1], RA [2], TTL [3]
                  CV Type: LSPV [2]
csr01#sh mpls l2transport summary
Destination address: 10.1.1.2, total number of vc: 1
  0 unknown, 1 up, 0 down, 0 admin down, 0 recovering, 0 standby, 0 hotstandby
  1 active vc on MPLS interface Tu0
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable Promiscuous mode in dSwitch.